# Using Java Keystore for google.com

Tags: java, keytool

Im trying to connect to https://www.google.com using the following apache example code:

```
/**
 * This example demonstrates how to create secure connections with a custom SSL
 * context.
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 */

public class ClientCustomSSL {

public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                .getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "my.keystore"));
        try {
            trustStore.load(instream, "123456".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            try {
                instream.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }

        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", 443, socketFactory);
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.google.com");

        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: "
                    + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

Im getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at ClientCustomSSL.main(ClientCustomSSL.java:71)
```

-keytool -list shows the following:

```
Keystore-Typ: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore enthält 3 Einträge

low, 19.03.2012, trustedCertEntry, 
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): 74:2C:31:92:E6:07:E4:24:EB:45:49:54:2B:E1:BB:C5:3E:61:74:E2
root, 19.03.2012, trustedCertEntry, 
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): C1:95:6D:C8:A7:DF:B2:A5:A5:69:34:DA:09:77:8E:3A:11:02:33:58
mid, 19.03.2012, trustedCertEntry, 
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): EC:07:10:03:D8:F5:A3:7F:42:C4:55:7F:65:6A:AE:86:65:FA:4B:02
```

I saved the all 3 certs (google.com and upper) in my browser by clicking the adressbar->to file and importet it with keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias xx -file xxxx.cer

what am i doing wrong`?
thanks in advance

Comment: But this link is not secure.I use IE 9 and the url is indeed `https` but there is no padlock.

Comment: if i comment out the first part from defining the keystore till registering the scheme i get following answer and no exceptions:
    executing requestGET https://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Response content length: -1
Shouldnt i get the html code of google.com as answer?

Comment: HTTP request headers are also encrypted over TLS.You are not accessing a secure link as far as I can see.

Comment: and dont i get the HTML code?

Comment: and why* dont i get the HTML code?